# Multidimensional javascript

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

Have an issue with multidimensional javascript, here is an example of what Im trying to do 
There are td tags in tr tags like these

```
<tr id="tr">
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

I want in every tr tag the last element to be deleted. This must happened on onchange event, but its not a point, I want the code to delete elements from the end in each tr tag.
Here how I see it

```
var trs = document.getElementsTagByName("tr");
var tds = document.getElementsTagByName("td");
var tr = document.getElementById("tr");
var td = document.getElementById("td");
for(var q = 1, a = trs.length; q < a; a-1) {
    for(var w = 1, s = tds.length; w > s; s-1) {
        //Here I want to be a condition, if as an example there will be 2 td 
        //from each tr I want to be deleted in one time  from tr's elements
        while( !2 ) {
            td.parent.revomeChild("td");
        }
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Element id must be unique within the page

Comment: Fixed it still doesnt work, I need them to be deleted by 2 or 3 elements in a time, when condition change. Not sure how will i do it with last-child. Why downvote????

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var trs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(var i=0; i<trs.length; i++){
  trs[i].removeChild(trs[i].lastElementChild)
}
```